# pgbouncer can not connect to server

Tags: postgresql-9.3, pgbouncer

i have install and configure pgbouncer on windows. pgbouncer service is running but when i connect it with postgres 9.6 it throws error '

> pgbouncer can not connect to server

' 
[create server with pgbouncer port](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1vqu.png)

```
pgbouncer configurations are:
postgres = host=127.0.0.1 port=4851
staging29-6-1016 = host=localhost port=4851 dbname=staging29-6-1016
listen_addr = *
listen_port = 6432
auth_type = md5
auth_file = C:\Program Files (x86)\PgBouncer\etc\userlist.txt
```

userlist.txt also contains md5 encrypted password

postgresql.conf file contains:

listen_addresses = '*'
port = 4851

kindly help me how to remove this error.

```
2017-08-03 15:23:33.429 2360 LOG C-00EA8FE0: postgres/postgres@[::1]:54985 login attempt: db=postgres user=postgres tls=no 
2017-08-03 15:23:33.429 2360 LOG C-00EA8FE0: postgres/postgres@[::1]:54985 closing because: pgbouncer cannot connect to server (age=0) 
2017-08-03 15:23:33.430 2360 WARNING C-00EA8FE0: postgres/postgres@[::1]:54985 Pooler Error: pgbouncer cannot connect to server
```

Comment: `pgbouncer` can't connect and other client (eg `psql`) can?..

Comment: yep.... you can connect it with psql.
please take a look on following link
http://technobytz.com/install-configure-pgbouncer-pooling-in-postgresql-1.html

Comment: what's that link?.. If boucer fails to connect because of postgres - postgres.log will have detail - please share

Comment: postgres log file is empty..... but pgbouncer log file has error

2017-08-03 15:23:33.429 2360 LOG C-00EA8FE0: postgres/postgres@[::1]:54985 login attempt: db=postgres user=postgres tls=no
2017-08-03 15:23:33.429 2360 LOG C-00EA8FE0: postgres/postgres@[::1]:54985 closing because: pgbouncer cannot connect to server (age=0)
2017-08-03 15:23:33.430 2360 WARNING C-00EA8FE0: postgres/postgres@[::1]:54985 Pooler Error: pgbouncer cannot connect to server

Comment: whats the output of `psql -h 127.0.0.1 -p 4851 -U postgres -d postgres` and `psql -h 127.0.0.1 -p 6432 -U postgres -d postgres`?..

Comment: @unknownuser: did you ever get this to work? I have a similar question posted here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/188526/how-to-successfully-connect-postgresql-9-6-5-to-pgbouncer-1-7-2

Comment: If postgresql log is empty (Assuming you have enabled connect logging) that means that it's not even getting to the point to connect to the server, then it means it's a local issue . I think you have issues with ipv6 here, you seem to be connecting using localhost(ipv6).